# Swift Connecting Page View Controller to View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode6

I am trying to connect the last page in my `Page View Controller` to another view controller.

In the Page View Controller I am looking at the method below as my last page and linking that to another view controller. However, it is not working. I receive a crash.

```
if (index == self.pageTitles.count) {
  let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
  return nil
}
```

Comment: Is the secondViewController instance in the story board set to the SecondViewController class as the custom class? Check where the crash is  occurring. Also in which method you are having this code?

Comment: @PradeepK code is in the viewDidLoad method. The SecondViewController is already created in the story board and the crash is just in the app delegate with SIGABRT

Comment: You should include your full code or the project to troubleshoot better.

Comment: This code doesn't look like it will ever execute. `index` is presumably the index of the current `pageTitles`, but it is zero-based, so it will never be equal to `pageTitles.count`.